# jquery select to fill an element

Tags: jquery, html, select

I have the following list:

```
<select id="selectprice" name="prod1">"
<option value="1">prod1</select>
<option value="2">prod2</select>
<option value="3">prod3</select>
</select>

<input type="text" id="valueprice" name="price_incl" size="4">
```

I want the following code to update my price when I select an option from dropdown:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("select[name='prod1']").change(function() {
         if($(this).val()==1) {
             $('#valueprice1').text( "21.95" );
           }// ect ect
     });
   });
</script>
```

But.. it does not work, and i cant seem to figure out why ;)

Regards

Comment: `<option value="1">prod1</select>`? should be `<option value="1">prod1</option>`

Comment: then `$('#valueprice').val("21.95");` not `$('#valueprice').text("21.95");`

Answer (score 0):

Missing the option closing tags -

```
<option value="1">prod1</option> // not select
```

And it is `val()` not `text()`

```
$('#valueprice').val( "21.95" );
```

The code will be -

```
$("select[name='prod1']").change(function() {
    if($(this).val()==2) {
         $('#valueprice').val( "21.95" );
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uaL9o0dn/)

Answer (score 0):

First, your id selector needs to be `#valueprice`, not `#valueprice1`

Also, close your `option` tags with `option`, not `select`

Finally, use `val` instead of `text`, as this is an `input` element

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("select[name='prod1']").change(function() {
         if($(this).val()==1) {
             $('#valueprice').val( "21.95" );
           }// ect ect
     });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectprice" name="prod1">
<option value="1">prod1</option>
<option value="2">prod2</option>
<option value="3">prod3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="valueprice" name="price_incl" size="4">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `val` instead of `text` to set the value of the element.

```
$('#valueprice1').val("21.95");
```

> Set the value of each element in the set of matched elements.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0):

2 Issues, the closing tag for option is `</option>` not `</select>`, then use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set input value

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select[name='prod1']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 1) {
      $('#valueprice').val("21.95");
    } // ect ect
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectprice" name="prod1">"
  <option value="1">prod1</option>
  <option value="2">prod2</option>
  <option value="3">prod3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="valueprice" name="price_incl" size="4">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not correctly closing your `options` tags and you need to use `val()` to set the value, see the corrections in the example below:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("select[name='prod1']").change(function() {

      if ($(this).val() == 1) {
        alert('prod1 selected')
        $('#valueprice1').val("21.95");
      } // ect ect
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectprice" name="prod1">"
  <option value="1">prod1</option>
  <option value="2">prod2</option>
  <option value="3">prod3</option>
</select>
```